# Using tweepy to access Twitter's Streaming API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently having trouble getting example code for using tweepy to access Twitter's Streaming API to run correctly (err...or at least how I expect it to run). I'm using a recent clone of tweepy from GitHub (labeled version 1.9) and Python 2.7.1.

I've tried example code from three sources, in each case using "twitter" as a test term for tracking:

1. O'Rilley Answers code: [How to Capture Tweets in Real-time with Twitter's Streaming API](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2605-how-to-capture-tweets-in-real-time-with-twitters-streaming-api/)
2. Andrew Robinson's blog: [Using Tweepy to access the Twitter Stream](http://andrewbrobinson.com/2011/07/15/using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-stream/)
3. Tweepy examples repository on GitHub (which, as Andrew Robinson has done, can be easily modified to support OAuth authentication): streamwatcher.py

In all three cases I get the same result: Authentication is successful, no errors are produced, and the main program loop seems to be executing w/o any problems. I see network usage jump to about 200KB/s, and the python process jumps to near 100% CPU usage, so I think data is being received. Nothing is output to the console, however.

I suspect that tweepy's Stream class is not calling the custom callback method for some reason. I've tried rewriting the callback methods in each example to produce output *whenever* they're called, which seems to confirm this. This is one very simple bit of test code based on Andrew Robinson's blog entry (with my app's keys removed, of course):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

access_token_key = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        print 'Ran on_status'

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error: ' + repr(status_code)
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        print 'Ok, this is actually running'


l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l)
#setTerms = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodnight', 'good morning']
setTerms = ['twitter']
streamer.filter(track = setTerms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this as well and fixed it on my local checkout by changing line 160 in streaming.py to

```
if delimited_string.strip().isdigit():
```

This seems to be a known issue/bug in Tweepy - should have checked the issues list before doing all that debugging :) -

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/173 
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/182

Comment: Thanks!!! Worked like a charm. Also, thanks for the suggestion to check the issues list on GitHub--that's probably what I really needed to know;-)