# Trying to use Tweepy/Twitters Streaming API and psycopg2 to populate a PostgreSQL database. Very close, one line off

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, tweepy, postgresql-9.2

I've been working on trying to populate a table in a PostreSQL database using Tweepy and Twitter's Streaming API. I'm extremely close, I believe I'm just one line away from getting it. I've looked at many examples including:
http://andrewbrobinson.com/2011/07/15/using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-stream/
http://blog.creapptives.com/post/14062057061/the-key-value-store-everyone-ignored-postgresql
[Python tweepy writing to sqlite3 db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432187/python-tweepy-writing-to-sqlite3-db)
[tweepy stream to sqlite database - invalid synatx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434205/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-invalid-synatx)
[Using tweepy to access Twitter's Streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970550/using-tweepy-to-access-twitters-streaming-api)
etc, etc

Im at the point where I can stream tweets quite easily using Tweepy, so I know my consumer key, consumer secret, access key and access secret are correct. I also have Postgres set up, and am successfully connecting to the database I created. I tested hard coded values into the table in my database using psycopg2 from a .py file, and that is also working. I am getting tweets streamed in based on keywords I select, and am successfully connected to a table in a database. Now I just need the tweets to stream into the table in my postgres database. Like I said, I am so close and any help would be so greatly appreciated.

This stripped down script inserts data into my desired table:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=teststreamtweets user=postgres password=x host=localhost")
    print "connected"
except:
    print "unable to connect"

namedict = (
    {"first_name":"Joshua", "last_name":"Drake"},
    {"first_name":"Steven", "last_name":"Foo"},
    {"first_name":"David", "last_name":"Bar"}
    )

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO testdata(first_name, last_name) VALUES (%(first_name)s, %(last_name)s)""", namedict);

conn.commit()
```

Below is the script I have been editing for a while now trying to get it to work:

```
import psycopg2
import time
import json
from getpass import getpass
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'x'
consumer_secret = 'x'
access_key = 'x'
access_secret = 'x'

connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=teststreamtweets user=postgres password=x host=localhost")
cursor = connection.cursor()

#always use this step to begin clean
def reset_cursor():
    cursor = connection.cursor()

class StreamWatcherListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print 'before cursor' + data
            connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=teststreamtweets user=postgres password=x host=localhost")
            cur = connection.cursor()
            print 'status is: ' + str(connection.status)
            #cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet_list VALUES (%s)" % (data.text))
            cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO tweets(tweet) VALUES (%(text)s)""", data);
            connection.commit()
            print '---------'
            print type(data)
            #print data
        except Exception as e:
            connection.rollback()
            reset_cursor()
            print "not saving"
            return 
        if cursor.lastrowid == None:
            print "Unable to save"

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error code = %s' % status_code
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print 'timed out.....'

print 'welcome'
auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth1)

l = StreamWatcherListener()
print 'about to stream'
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth = auth1, listener = l)

setTerms = ['microsoft']
#stream.sample()
stream.filter(track = setTerms)
```

Sorry if it's a bit messy of code, but have been trying many options. Like I said any suggestions, links to helpful examples, etc would be greatly appreciated as I've tried everything I can think of and am now resorting to a long walk. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why you are using classes for this, and then why you don't have `__init__` defined in your class. Seems complicated.

Here is a basic version of the functions I use to do this stuff. I've only ever used sqlite for it, but the syntax looks basically the same. Maybe you can get something from this.

```
def retrieve_tweets(numtweets=10, *args):
    """
    This function optionally takes one or more arguments as keywords to filter tweets.
    It iterates through tweets from the stream that meet the given criteria and sends them 
    to the database population function on a per-instance basis, so as to avoid disaster 
    if the stream is disconnected.

    Both SampleStream and FilterStream methods access Twitter's stream of status elements.
    """   
    filters = []
    for key in args:
        filters.append(str(key))
    if len(filters) == 0:
        stream = tweetstream.SampleStream(username, password)  
    else:
        stream = tweetstream.FilterStream(username, password, track=filters)
    try:
        count = 0
        while count < numtweets:       
            for tweet in stream:
                # a check is needed on text as some "tweets" are actually just API operations
                # the language selection doesn't really work but it's better than nothing(?)
                if tweet.get('text') and tweet['user']['lang'] == 'en':   
                    if tweet['retweet_count'] == 0:
                        # bundle up the features I want and send them to the db population function
                        bundle = (tweet['id'], tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['retweet_count'], tweet['text'])
                        db_initpop(bundle)
                        break
                    else:
                        # a RT has a different structure.  This bundles the original tweet.  Getting  the
                        # retweets comes later, after the stream is de-accessed.
                        bundle = (tweet['retweeted_status']['id'], tweet['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'], \
                                  tweet['retweet_count'], tweet['retweeted_status']['text'])
                        db_initpop(bundle)
                        break
            count += 1
    except tweetstream.ConnectionError, e:
        print 'Disconnected from Twitter at '+time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) \
        +'.  Reason: ', e.reason

def db_initpop(bundle):
    """
    This function places basic tweet features in the database.  Note the placeholder values:
    these can act as a check to verify that no further expansion was available for that method.
    """
    #unpack the bundle 
    tweet_id, user_sn, retweet_count, tweet_text = bundle
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO tblTweets VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", \
        (tweet_id, user_sn, retweet_count, tweet_text, 'cleaned text', 'cleaned retweet text'))
    conn.commit()
    print 'Database populated with tweet '+str(tweet_id)+' at '+time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
```

Good luck!